# Create a data frame with headings as column names and <li> tag content as rows, then print this data frame into a text file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the main body data from [this website](https://www.bankersadda.com/17th-september-2021-daily-gk-update/)

I want to get a data frame (or any other object which makes life easier) as output with subheadings as column names and body under the subheading as lines under that column.

My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.bankersadda.com/17th-september-2021-daily-gk-update/"
page = requests.get(url)
html = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml') #"html.parser")
article = soup.find(class_ = "entry-content")

headings = []
lines = []

my_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(100))
for strong in article.findAll('strong'):
    if strong.parent.name =='p':
        if strong.find(text=re.compile("News")):
            headings.append(strong.text)
            
#headings
k=0
for ul in article.findAll('ul'):
    for li in ul.findAll('li'):
        lines.append(li.text)
    lines= lines + [""]
    my_df[k] = pd.Series(lines)
    k=k+1
        
my_df
```

I want to use the "headings" list to get the data frame column names.

Clearly I'm not writing the correct logic. I explored nextSibling, descendants and other attributes too, but I can't figure out the correct logic. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the headline, use `.find_next()` to get that news article list. Then add them into a list under the headline as a key in a dictionary. Then simply use `pd.concat()` with `ignore_index=False`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.bankersadda.com/17th-september-2021-daily-gk-update/"
page = requests.get(url)
html = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml') #"html.parser")
article = soup.find(class_ = "entry-content")

headlines = {}
news_headlines = article.find_all('p',text=re.compile("News"))
for news_headline in news_headlines:
    end_of_news = False
    sub_title = news_headline.find_next('p')
    headlines[news_headline.text] = []
    #print(news_headline.text)
    while end_of_news == False:
        headlines[news_headline.text].append(sub_title.text)
        articles = sub_title.find_next('ul')
        for li in articles.findAll('li'):
            headlines[news_headline.text].append(li.text)
            #print(li.text)
        sub_title = articles.find_next('p')
        if 'News' in sub_title.text or sub_title.text == '' :
            end_of_news = True
    
            
df_list = []
for headings, lines in headlines.items():
    temp = pd.DataFrame({headings:lines})
    df_list.append(temp)
    

my_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=False, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print(my_df)
                                       National News  ...                                    Obituaries News
0  1. Cabinet approves 100% FDI under automatic r...  ...  11. Eminent Kashmiri Writer Aziz Hajini passes...
1  The Union Cabinet, chaired by Prime Minister N...  ...  Noted writer and former secretary of Jammu and...
2  A total of 9 structural and 5 process reforms ...  ...  He has over twenty books in Kashmiri to his cr...
3  Change in the definition of AGR: The definitio...  ...  12. Former India player and Mohun Bagan great ...
4  Rationalised Spectrum Usage Charges: The month...  ...  Former India footballer and Mohun Bagan captai...
5  Four-year Moratorium on dues: Moratorium has b...  ...  Bhabani Roy helped Mohun Bagan win the Rovers ...
6  Foreign Direct Investment (FDI): The governmen...  ...  13. 2 times Olympic Gold Medalist Yuriy Sedykh...
7  Auction calendar fixed: Spectrum auctions will...  ...  Double Olympic hammer throw gold medallist Yur...
8     Important takeaways for all competitive exams:  ...  He set the world record for the hammer throw w...
9      Minister of Communications: Ashwini Vaishnaw.  ...  He won his first gold medal at the 1976 Olympi...

[10 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm!
Only part I didn't understand is the last section. Specifically the line --temp = pd.DataFrame({headings:lines})
What is getting saved here in temp?

Comment: It’s making a dataframe of 1 column. Column name is 'headings' And the rows are a list 'lines'

Comment: Hey, found a problem with the code.
It is only extracting the first news item under each heading and not extracting all the news items.

Comment: ah. Ya I see what you mean. I was just working off your code. I'll fix that in a bit

Comment: @MRD, give it try now.

Comment: @MRD, why did you unaccept the solution?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the quick reply. It works now as intended. It took me some time to understand the changes.
I unaccepted the original solution because I thought you'll be making another post and I'll have to accept that as a solution. Didn't knew that you can amend the already posted code.
Thanks again.